# Firestore SDK newer version in web browser?

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, google-cloud-firestore, persistent-storage

I am not quite sure when this message first appeared in Chrome console, but it is there now and I do not know how to fix this.

> [code=failed-precondition]: A newer version of the Firestore SDK was previously used and so the persisted data is not compatible with the version of the SDK you are now using. The SDK will operate with persistence disabled. If you need persistence, please re-upgrade to a newer version of the SDK or else clear the persisted IndexedDB data for your app to start fresh.

I have tried `await firebase.firestore().clearPersistence();` after this error occured (i e after `enablePersistence({ synchronizeTabs: true })`), but that did not help.

Does anyone know how to fix it? Documentation?

EDIT: I am using version 7.2.1 of the Firebase SDK in the web client. Previously I used 6.6.1.

---

EDIT 2: Today it is suddenly working again. Without any changes on my side. I have no idea what is going on. I will keep my eyes on a few things:

- Did Google do anything on their side?
- The service worker (PWA). Does it really update things as I expect?
- Chrome. I use "Empty Cache and Hard Reload". Sometimes I see strange things (old breakpoints coming back etc).

I did restart Chrome, but the problem was still there immediately after that.

Hm, I did one thing. I was loading my sign-in script too early (just a bug). Fixed that. Could it be that?

Comment: How do you initialize Firebase? See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup/#add-sdks-initialize

Comment: @ItangSanjana I use the "reserved Hosting URLs", like `<script src="/__/firebase/7.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>`. Was there anything special you were thinking of?

Comment: Nothing special. I thought you were on localhost and were suspicious of the old version of firebase-tools. :)